# How do I wrap dangerous linux commands with verification prompt

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

**Question:**  How can I wrap linux commands to ask for verification before executing the command?

**Example:**

```
$> shutdown -r now
Please verify the host you are shutting down by typing the hostname: myhost.example.com
Verification passed, shutting down now
```

**Justification:** We recently had an incident where a production engineer was on the wrong machine when they ran a destructive command, management has asked us to put in verification checks for certain destructive commands.

**Challenge:** We need to wrap a variety of command types, some may be `systemctl` commands, scripts, or binaries being executed.

Comment: The downside to this is much like aliasing `rm` to `rm -i`. People get used to it and therefore get sloppy about using it. Then when they hit a server that doesn't have the safety net they get burned.

Answer (score 1):

1. Move the binary to a location that is *not* in the $PATH
2. Create a bash script to do the verification that you want and store it at a location *inside* your path.

```
mv /sbin/shutdown /opt/shutdown
touch /sbin/shutdown
chmod +x /sbin/shutdown
```

Then replace it with a bash script that does what you want.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "do whatever" 
/opt/shutdown $@
```

The line `/opt/shutdown $@` will pass any and all command line arguments to the *real* binary.

Comment: Not quoting `$@` is a bug. It should be `/opt/shutdown "$@"`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use aliases created by your favorite configuration management system targeting critical systems.

```bsh
you_sure() {
  if [[ $- =~ i ]] # only on interactive shells
  then
    read -p 'OPERATION ON LIVE PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENT! ARE YOU SURE? [N/y]: ' -n 1 -r
    echo
  fi

  if [[ ! $- =~ i || $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
  then
    "$CMD" "$@"
  fi
}

alias shutdown='CMD=shutdown you_sure'
```

This also allows simple bypass by preceding the command with a slash: `$ \shutdown -r now`